# What's the imperative form for "to be" in Portuguese of Portugal?

Tags: gramática

What's the imperative form for "to be" in Portuguese of Portugal?
For example, if I want to say "**Be** calm my friend".

Answer (score 11):

Your question is both easier and harder than it appears.

The easy part is that Portugal uses “familiar” second-person *tu* imperatives with friends and children, which in affirmative commands preserve the stem vowel of the verb. These are unlike the third-person imperatives one would use with *você* or *o senhor* with people you’re being more polite with for whatever reason, which being third-person imperatives instead of second-person ones would have to swap the stem vowel the way a present-subjunctive form does. (Most of Brazil uses only *você* forms, not *tu* forms the way Portugal does.)

The hard part is that you might be tempted merely to look up the second-person imperative form of *be* and use that. Then you’d have to think about whether this is more of a “stative” *be* that would therefore require a form of the verb *estar* as in *Está quieto* for be quiet, versus whether this is instead more of an “essence” *be* that would therefore require a form of the verb *ser* like a mother telling her son to be a good boy by saying *Sê bom!*

But you’d still be barking up the wrong tree as they say in English, because *be calm my friend*, or just plain *settle down*, could easily call for using a different verb altogether: ***ficar***. Even though it’s a common verb, it still isn’t one most learners would think of using for *be* because they’d be translating too literally. So for your phrase, I would just say *Fica tranquilo, meu amigo* for a guy or *Fica tranquila, minha amiga* for a girl.

There are various other possible ways of saying this, but those are the forms you need to know about for what you’ve asked about.

Comment: Whereas, depending on context, I'd probably just say *tem calma* (for someone who's agitated); *fica tranquilo/a* or, more commonly in coloquial/popular speech in Portugal, *fica descansado/a* (*everything will be ok*; for someone who's worried).

Comment: Learner here. Would "Seja tranquilo" work? I've heard "Seja forte" many times.

Comment: @ReversedEngineer No, you wouldn't use *Seja tranquilo* because that's a 3rd-person *você* from not a 2nd-person *tu* form like *Sê* is, but also because you don't use *ser* for a state like this. Your *Seja forte* more means "Be a strong person."  If you were using *você* forms (maybe you're in Brazil or being formal), then Jacinto's rather nice *tem calma* with *tu* becomes *tenha calma* with *você*. Here the verb is actually "have" but would translate into "be" idiomatically in English. Often different verbs get used in different languages, so word-for-word translation fails there.